# How to efficiently output n items per line from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, file-io, numpy

I've got a 1-D numpy array that is quite long.  I would like to efficiently write it to a file, putting N space separated values per line in the file.  I have tried a couple of methods, but both have big issues.

First, I tried reshaping the array to be N columns wide.  Given a file handle, f:

```
myArray.reshape(-1, N)
for row in myArray:
    print >> f, " ".join(str(val) for val in row)
```

This was quite efficient, but requires the array to have a multiple of N elements.  If the last row only contained 1 element (and N was larger than one) I would only want to print 1 element... not crash.

Next, I tried printing with a counter, and inserting a line break after every Nth element:

```
i = 1
for val in myArray:
    if i < N:
        print >> f, str(val)+" ",
        i+=1
    else:
        print >> f, str(val)
        i = 1
```

This worked fine for any length array, but was extremely slow (taking at least 10x longer than my first option).  I am outputting many files, from many arrays, and can not use this method due to speed.

Any thoughts on an efficient way to do this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(myArray), N):
    print " ".join([str(v) for v in myArray[i:i+N]])
    # or this 
    # print " ".join(map(str, myArray[i:i+N].tolist()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `try`/`except` to your reshaping approach to print the last elements to the output file:

```
myArray.reshape(-1, N)
try:
    for row in myArray:
        print >> f, " ".join(str(val) for val in row)
except: # add the exact type of error here to be on the save side
    # just print the last (incomplete) row
    print >> f, " ".join(str(val) for val in myArray[-1])
```